# Using ArrayList from Activity in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have an arrayList in the MainActivity, and I'm using alarmManager to show notifications when the app is closed. I don't know how I can use that arraylist in the BroadcastReceiver "inside onReceive() method" and get data from that arraylist to show it in the Notifications. I also want to be able to remove the element from the arraylist that has already been shown in the notification.
anyway this my code, I hope you can help me !

-MainActivity :

```
 NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
private static final String ACTION_NOTIFY = "com.example.android.standup.ACTION_NOTIFY";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(ACTION_NOTIFY);
    final PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
            (this, NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    ToggleButton toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.alarmToggle);
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b){
                long triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+10000;

                long repeatInterval = 180000;
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, repeatInterval, notifyPendingIntent);
            }else {
                mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
                alarmManager.cancel(notifyPendingIntent);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

AlarmReceiver Class :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Intent contentIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                    (context, createID(), contentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .setContentTitle("Hello")
                    .setContentText("Notification Text")
                    .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationManager.notify(createID(), builder.build());


}
public int createID(){
    Date now = new Date();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("ddHHmmss",  Locale.US).format(now));
    return id;
}
```

}

Thank you !

Comment: Are you familiar with notification actions?

Comment: I've just started studying notification, so no I'm not